# How can I choose MVC3 controller template in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010

I was following the MVC3 tutorial at [asp.net](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/adding-a-controller) and I noticed that the when I tried to add a new controller I was only given the option of specifying the controller name unlike how it's shown in the screenshot in the tutorial. I didn't have an **Advance Options...** button either. Since nothing was selected was the additional options I didn't worry too much about it but [later on](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/accessing-your-model%27s-data-from-a-controller) in the tutorial they do change these options.

Why do I not see these options? Could it have anything to do with the fact that I'm running Visual Studio 2010 Premium SP1 and they having used Visual Web Developer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have installed the [`ASP.NET MVC 3 Tools Update`](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1491) (For VS2010 that would be the `AspNetMVC3ToolsUpdateSetup.exe` file).

Answer (score 2):

While following the tutorial u may have installed the entity framework and added the DbContext. Adding the DbContext changes some default values i guess. Installing the update for  MVC3 tools at
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1491 will work.. (It worked for me!)
Hope this helps